# Have an include() for specific content with PHP

Tags: php

I have several files with a header and a footer, let's say `file1.php`, `file2.php` and `file3.php`

These files `include()` the files `header.php` and `footer.php.`

Now the concern is this... Each page has to load a general header content with certain css styles, but also a -specific- style for such page. This also happens on the footer: it loads a bunch of scripts for all pages, but a specific script for a specific page.

How can I achieve this?
I certainly don't want to put the specific script on the specific page because it might not only be attached to one, but several ones, the js script or the css style can be attached to five or ten pages...

I was thinking a `switch()` for each case in the header or footer page, then any conditional (such as `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`) in the other pages, but how can I do the include thing? is it include() what I'm looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're over-thinking this, and have over-complicated your site quite a bit.  Include what you need, where you need it, and consider using a template engine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much beyond the scope of Stackoverflow but why not.

---

**Switch inside the template**

I see you added that you were thinking of using a switch.  Here is an example of something simple you could do.

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>...</title>
   <?php switch(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php')) {
   case 'file1': ?>
       <script src="file1.js"></script>
   <?php break;
   case 'file2': ?>
       <script src="file2.js"></script>
   <?php break;
   }
   ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Just sample code in-between the case and break.  This code initiates a switch on the file name, file1.php would be 'file1'.

---

**Output Buffering**

What else you could do is output buffering.  Let's say you have a template at file1.tpl.php, then you have header.php.  Inside file1.php, you could do this:

```
ob_start();
include "file1.tpl.php";
$content = ob_get_clean();
include "header.php";
```

Everything processed from file1.tpl.php will be stored in *$content*. Then inside header.php, you load *$content* where you see fit:

```
<html><head><?= $content ?></head><body>
```

Comment: yeah, thad did the trick!, thank you very much, I did that on the header file, and then simply added the include on every other page... Now I have it centralized..

Comment: @DanielFelipe, I added another example of using output buffering with separate includes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation might go like so:

Define a global styles array (say, in a config.php file that gets included on every page), which holds an array of CSS files that can be load:

```
global $styles = array(
    "foo" => "/styles/foo.css",
    "bar" => "/styles/bar.css",
);
```

with the value holding the path to the relevant CSS file.

At the top of the page in question, setup a variable to determine which CSS files to include:

```
$activeStyles = array('foo');
```

Then, in your header.php, check for the existence of the variable, and whether or not it contains any values:

```
<?php
    if(isset($activeStyles) && count($activeStyles) > 0) {
        # iterate through the array, generating the appropriate <link /> tags
        foreach($activeStyles as $styleKey) {
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $styles[$styleKey] ?>" />

<?php

        }
    }
?>
```

You would use the same concept for scripts.